# How to pipe (/stream) big file (video,pdf,any...) from aws s3 to node.js express res?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, pipe

Currently i have tried many ways like

```
const S3FS = require('s3fs');

s3fsImpl = new S3FS(bucketName, {
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
})

var range = 'undefined' !== typeof req.headers.range ? req.headers.range : 'bytes=0-';
var positions = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
var start = parseInt(positions[0], 10);
var total = details.ContentLength;
var end = positions[1] ? parseInt(positions[1], 10) : total - 1;
var chunksize = (end - start) + 1;

res.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
res.status(206);
res.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + total);
res.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
res.setHeader("Content-Length", chunksize);

s3fsImpl.createReadStream(key,{ start: start, end: end }).pipe(res);
```

( same with  const AWS = require('aws-sdk') )
It just hangs up and no video occured. Currently i just do pipe without chunks, but it take video too long to occur, and seems i need to implement chunks stream from s3. So how can i pipe video, pddf, or other big files from the aws s3?

Comment: How big is the video?

Comment: As far as I remember the limit for Amazon chubk size is somewhere around 5g's. And anyone sane would not implement this as a 5g chunk in node (not because it wouldn't make sense, but because it would be hard and wouldn't make sense). So unless you are over the size the issue doesn't seem to be in the code you posted